# VS2012 Find Shelvsets, show comment

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, unshelve, shelveset

In Visual Studio 2012, the Find Shelvsets window, how can I customize the result list?

The name of the shelvset and the date are displayed, but I would like to see
the comments and full timestamp as in VS2010.

Comment: You can't as far as I know. You could use the TFS SideKicks to find the shelveset you're after with more details http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Answer (score 1):

From the Visual Studio command line you can run the following command 
`tf shelvesets /owner:*`
It will display more information that might be what you are looking for.

Also, from MSDN:
[Suspend Your Work and Manage Your Shelvesets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx)

After you have a list of shelvesets (explained in “To find a shelveset”) in the Find Shelvesets page, double-click the shelveset to view it.
The Shelveset Details page appears.
[image: Shelve-set Details]